# How to dump usb stick with corrupt partition table?

Tags: linux, bash, hardware, usb, data-recovery

Question at the bottom.

When I insert the 8GB usb stick I get this in `dmesg`

```
[168699.879019] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 24 using ehci-pci
[168699.994177] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0917
[168699.994181] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[168699.994184] usb 1-4: Product: IS917
[168699.994187] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Innostor Technology Corp.
[168699.994733] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[168699.995539] scsi host9: usb-storage 1-4:1.0
[168700.996574] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Innostor NAND Flash       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[168700.996859] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[168701.001686] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

which leads me to think, that the hardware in the usb stick works.

When I do `cat /dev/sg3` nothing happens.

```
# fdisk /dev/sdc
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdc: No medium found
# lsusb|grep Inno
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 1f75:0917 Innostor Technology Corporation 
# ll /dev/bus/usb/001/024 
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 23 Jan 14 15:04 /dev/bus/usb/001/024
```

So I am thinking that the MBR have been corrupted.

**Question**

Does anyone have an idea how I can dump the raw device to a file, so I can look at it in a hex editor?

Comment: That I guessed wrong ;)

Comment: What happens when you try to 'dd' the device to a file?
dd if=/dev/sdc of=/path/to/file bs=512

Comment: @VinceBerk Then I get 50 bytes.

Comment: That thing is dead. Toss it in the bin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you cant cat raw device it looks like whole thing is not responding... but if you somehow manage to make it work:

first and most important, dump whole usb stick to file, using `ddrescue` if neccesary, in case shit hits the fan

Then use either `testdisk` or `gpart` to recover partition table, those programs guesses start of partiton based on filesystem headers